# Как убрать расстояние между контейнерами PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlayout, spacing

При создании двух контейнеров между ними появляется белая полоска.

Как ее убрать?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(1000,500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.content = QFrame()
        self.left_bar = QFrame()

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35);")

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(80)

        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.content)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не изменил строки, просто упорядочил их, чтобы понять что происходит и сразу все стало на место.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

#        self.setMinimumSize(1000,500)
        self.resize(1000,500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,145);")        
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        
        self.content = QFrame()
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,135,35);")
        
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()        
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.content)
        
        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(145,45,45);")
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(80)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы просто бог))

Comment: А из-за чего не получилось-то у меня? Только из-за того, что я не указал self у self.hbox? Но я же написал self.setLayout(self.hbox)

Comment: @Bitchdragon нет, не из-за этого. Я не анализировал. Попробуйте в своем коде `self.hbox.setSpacing(0)` сразу за строкой `self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Тогда снова появляется полоска

Comment: @Bitchdragon sorry, нет времени анализировать ваш плохо форматированный текст. Лучше поймите, как обычно выглядит структура приложения, глядя на мой код.

Comment: Понял, попробую